# Pulling out a column in all records in a Sqlite table into a concatenated string in Haskell with Persist

Tags: sqlite, haskell, select, persistent

I'm trying to learn Haskell, specifically Snap, Blaze HTML5 and Persist.  I would like to take every row in a table, select a single column from it, and then concatenate the values into a single string.

I've previously worked with C#'s LINQ quite extensively and under Entity Framework I could do it like this:

```
String.Join(", ", dbContext.People.Select(p => p.Name));
```

This would compile down to `SELECT Name FROM People`, with C# then concatenating those rows into a string with ", " in between.

To try and get the concatenation part right, I put this together, which seems to work:

```
intercalate ", " $ map show [1..10]
```

(it counts 1-9, concatenates with ", " in between the items)

However, I can't get this to work with Database.Persist.Sqlite.  I'm not sure I quite understand the syntax here in Haskell.  To contact the DB and retrieve the rows, I have to call: (as far as I understand)

```
runSqlite "TestDB" $ selectList ([] :: [Filter Person]) [] 0 0
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to get the list out of `runSqlite`.  `runSqlite` doesn't return the type I'm after, so I can't use the return value of runSqlite.  How would I do this?

Thank you for reading.

---

To clarify:

Snap requires that I define a function to return the HTML I wish to send back to the client making the HTTP request.  This means that:

```
page = runSqlite "TestDB" $ do
    {pull data from the DB)
```

Is no-go as I can't return the data via the `runSqlite` call, and as far as I know I can't have a variable in the `page` function which is set within the `runSqlite` `do` block.  All examples I can find just write to IO in the `runSqlite` `do` block, which is not what needs to be done here.

Answer (score 1):

The type of [runSqlite](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/persistent-sqlite/Database-Persist-Sqlite.html#v%3arunSqlite) is:

```
runSqlite :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadIO m)  => Text -> SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m)) a -> m a
```

And the type of [selectList](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/persistent/Database-Persist-Class.html#v%3aselectList) is:

```
[Filter val] -> [SelectOpt val] -> m [Entity val]
```

So, you can actually, use the nice `do` notation of Monad, to extract it:

```
runSqlite "TestDB" $ do
  myData <- selectList ([] :: [Filter Person]) [] 0 0
  -- Now do stuff with myData
```

The `<-` thing gets the list out of the monad. I would suggest you to go through this [chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) to get an idea of how Persistent is used. Note that the chapters in the book assume a basic Haskell understanding.

---

> The issue is that I want to use the selectList outside of runSqlite as
>   I need to pass the concatenated string to a Blaze HTML5 tag builder:
>   body $ do p (concatenated list...)

For this case, just define a function that does your intended task:

```
myLogic :: [SqlColumnData] -> String -- Note that SqlColumnData is hypothetical
myLogic xs = undefined
```

And then just call them appropriately in your `main` function:

```
main = runSqlite "TestDB" $ do
  myData <- selectList ([] :: [Filter Person]) [] 0 0
  let string = myLogic myData
  -- do any other remaining stuff
```

Comment: The issue is that I want to use the selectList outside of runSqlite as I need to pass the concatenated string to a Blaze HTML5 tag builder:

    body $ do
        p (concatenated list...)

Thanks for your answer, I should have been clearer about my intended use.

Comment: Write a pure function which actually uses the data from the `selectList`. At the end just call them appropriately (maybe in `main` function). I would suggest you to learn more of Haskell so that this technique becomes obvious to you.

Comment: @jameswilddev I have updated the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Hmm.  There are some pointers there, but I still cannot see how to solve this for my exact problem.  If in the example at the bottom there I replace main with the function I'm trying to write, I need to use something evaluated inside the runSqlite do block as the return value of the function.  I'm continuing to read up on the overall syntax as I have been the last two days, but I'm not seeing anything which allows me to do this.

Comment: The reason for needing to do this is that I need to execute this query in a Snap function, so the result needs to be returned, unless I'm misunderstanding and Blaze's p has side effects, which seems to run counter to a "pure functional" language.

Answer (score 1):

It hadn't clicked that if I didn't use a `do` block with `runSqlite`, the result of the last call in the statement was the return value of the statement - this makes total sense.

https://gist.github.com/egonSchiele/5400694

In this example (not mine) the `readPosts` function does exactly what I'm after and cleared up some Haskell syntax confusion.

Thank you for your help @Sibi.